# React-data-grid giving warning when using Basic DropDownEditor

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

Here's the versions I'm using for react-data-grid. Running app on Chrome.

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-data-grid": "^2.0.8",
"react-data-grid-addons": "^2.0.17",
```

I am replicating the [Build-In-Editors](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/built-in-editors) example from the main website. The grid itself is operating as intended but I'm getting the following warnings in Chrome's console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `options[0]` supplied to `DropDownEditor`.
in DropDownEditor (created by HomePage)
in HomePage (created by RouterContext)
in div (created by App)
in App (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in `DropDownFormatter`, but its value is `undefined`.
in DropDownFormatter (created by HomePage)
in HomePage (created by RouterContext)
in div (created by App)
in App (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router
```

Here's the code snippet that set's up the code for React Data Grid component:

Imports:

```
import {Editors, Formatters} from 'react-data-grid-addons';
const { DropDownEditor } = Editors;
const { DropDownFormatter } = Formatters;
```

Parameter setup:

```
const titleTypes = [
        { id: 'bug', value: 'bug', text: 'Bug', title: 'Bug' },
        { id: 'improvement', value: 'improvement', text: 'Improvement', title: 'Improvement' },
        { id: 'epic', value: 'epic', text: 'Epic', title: 'Epic' },
        { id: 'story', value: 'story', text: 'Story', title: 'Story' }
    ];

    const TitleTypesEditor = <DropDownEditor options={titleTypes}/>;
    const TitleTypesFormatter = <DropDownFormatter options={titleTypes}/>;

    this.state = {
        columns: [{key: 'id', name: 'ID'}, {key: 'title', name: 'Title',
            editable: true, editor: TitleTypesEditor, formatter: TitleTypesFormatter}],
        rows: [{id:1, title: 'title1'}, {id:2, title: 'bug'}]
    };
```

Rendering the component...

```
  <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this.state.columns}
            rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
            rowHeight={50}
            minHeight={200}
            rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
            enableCellSelect={true}
            onGridRowsUpdated={this.handleGridRowsUpdated}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Editors.AutoComplete` instead of `DropDownEditor` and `DropDownFormatter`.

```
   import {Editors} from 'react-data-grid-addons';


   const TitleTypesEditor = <Editors.AutoComplete options={titleTypes}/>;
   const TitleTypesFormatter = <Editors.AutoComplete options={titleTypes}/>;
```